# /8 base subnetting

Tags: subnet

I have a question on subnetting, the below question asks for the subnetting a /8 base network. I do not understand how to have at least 64 networks available while subnetting. I have checked the internet and I am confused between the total hosts and total servers. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

**Q. Given a /8 base network (e.g. 10.0.0.0), show how to subnet it so there are at least 64 networks available.**

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks for that link, but I am not sure if I got the answer from it :(

Comment: Well, two raised to which power is 64? Hmm?

Comment: There is a specific section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to the above linked question that explains exactly how to subnet a network into a number of equal-sized networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin I see what you mean, I found the "Subnetting IPv4 Networks" part in the thread and I understood how to go about this. Thanks a ton!! :)

Comment: @Zac67, 2 power 6, gotcha mate!! :)